# Shopping cart price rule for child SKU of configurable products does not work

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

Im trying un-sucessfully to get a shopping cart price rule to activate
at checkout. OK what I am trying to accomplish is if you buy 2 of any of
the SKU's listed "all SKU's are attribute choices of a configurable
product if that is any help" the buyer will receive a 50% discount on
the second bottle.

CONDITIONS 
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
If total quantity equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching
ANY  of these conditions: 
SKU  is one of  SKU1, SKU2, SKU3

ACTION 
Percent of the Product Price Discounted 
25 0, 0, NO NO NO for the rest

If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE : SKU  is one of  SKU1, SKU2, SKU3

I have tried variation of this however nothing whatsoever happens on the checkout. 
Cron is active as I believe this has an affect on rules and all attribute choices have promo rules active.
The coupon is also set to no coupon.

MY question is twofold. First can any see any glaringly obvious error in the setup as I was following the Magento price rules recipes which gives this exact instruction for setting up a similar rule.
Secondly is there a way to step through or debug Magento rules as they are activated?

Thank in advance...

Comment: Screenshot please

Comment: Here are the images as requested.!(http://www.vaperit.co.uk/stack/one.jpg)
!(http://www.vaperit.co.uk/stack/two.jpg)

Comment: @Richard could you upload the images to the question. I think the links provided have died :(

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in magento 1.7 and some earlier version with shopping cart rules and conditions.

The condition tab works perfectly, as it checks all cart items - child and parent.

But the action tab does not, as it checks only parent items and does not "see" child SKUs.

Possible workarounds:

1. Set action on configurable items only
2. Modify the input array of products for action check ( replace parent skus with the child) and restore it after the validation.
3. Some extensions for advanced shopping cart rules may have this bug fixed.

Comment: we have the opposite in M1938: where we need to filter by a parent attribute in cart rules... (pack size, the child/simple does not have this attribute) : so we cannot process these orders, because the cart rules check the simple products ... but not the parents. Any ideas?